# Relational Laravel Many to Many not Working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I made many to many relationships for admin and school tables. "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `admin_school` (`admin_id`, `school_id`) values (91, 2))"

Table :

1. admins
2. schools
3. admin_school (pivot table)

Here is structure pivot table
[image]

Model Admin

```
public function schools(){        
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\School', 'admin_school', 'admin_id', 'school_id');
}
```

Model School

```
public function admins(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin', 'admin_school', 'admin_id', 'school_id');
}
```

Controller

```
$stateAction = Admin::create($data);
$stateAction->schools()->attach($input["data"]["school_id"]);
```

Comment: `belongsToMany('App\Admin' ...)` missing `Models` in the namespace there? Also, since you've followed Eloquent naming conventions you only need to pass the first parameter to `belongsToMany` in both relationships. Eloquent will infer the rest for you.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter nothing, the namespace is correct. i have try to pass the first param only, and still got same error

Comment: Can you include your migration files? I see `admin_id` and `school_id` are different types, might be the problem there.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter i am create table manually at db, i dont use migration, maybe when i not use migration cause this problem?. for type data in table admins (id(bigint(20) unsigned Auto Increment) and table school (bigint(20) Auto Increment). please help me, iam stuck over 2 days

Comment: are you using the correct database? as the sql error says that `admin_id` field doesn't exist

Comment: @lagbox yes iam using correct database,. i know the error says that admin_id field doesnt exist, but the database, table or field is already exist. i have many time to check the table. but still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your relationship definition, foreign_key come first an local_key come after in relation, But you mention local_key, First and foreign_key after that in admins relationship.

```
public function admins(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin', 'admin_school', 'school_id', 'admin_id'  );
}
```

Comment: actually, i have to try this way, but iam still get the same error.. i have try many ways..

Comment: i have check the database too, and its fine. i attach the structure table in my post above. i dont know what the problem, please help me

Comment: yes i have skype and teamviewer, how? want using skype or teamviewer?